# EntityFramework not saving null and false value

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to update a record using EntityFramework 6 by attaching a disconnected entity. I want to update a single boolean field to **false** but it doesn't work. I have used sql server profiler and EF doesn't generate an update statement when calling SaveChanges on the context. But if i set the value to **true**, it works. Example:

This doesn't work:

```
 private void UpdateUser()
 {
    var user = new User { ID = 5 };
    this.Context.Users.Attach(user);

    user.Locked = false;
    this.Context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

This works:

```
 private void UpdateUser()
 {
    var user = new User { ID = 5 };
    this.Context.Users.Attach(user);

    user.Locked = true;
    this.Context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

I can fix by marking the property as modified like this:

```
this.Context.Entry(user).Property(e => e.Locked).IsModified = true;
```

But don't understand why does it work if the value is **true** and not if the value is **false**. There is a similar issue when trying to set a field to null.

There's probably something wrong with the entity data model or database but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default value for `Boolean` is `false`, so setting to `false` after attaching won't flag the property as changed.

You can load the entity first, then do your modifications then save changes.

```
var user = db.Users.Find(5);
user.Locked = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or you can attach the entity with the field you want to update set to a different value for Boolean fields

```
var user = new User { Id = 5, Locked = true; };
db.Users.Attach(user);
user.Locked = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: var user = new User { Id = 5, Locked = !valueToSet; };
db.Users.Attach(user);
user.Locked = valueToSet;
db.SaveChanges(); You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

False is the default value of boolean field, and, thus, setting false again will not report to change tracker that the property was changed. as a result it is not part of insert/update statement.
If it is database first approach, your property should look similar to this(see the setter):

```
public global::System.Boolean Locked
{
            get
            {
                return _Locked;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_Locked != value)
                {
                    OnLockedChanging(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanging("Locked");
                    _Locked = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanged("Locked");
                    OnLockedChanged();
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for the same question here:

```
     var user = new User { Id = 5, Locked = true; };
     db.Users.Attach(user);
     user.Locked = false;
     db.SaveChanges();
```

above solutions is not worked for me, but below code is worked for me.

```
     var user = new User { Id = 5, Locked = true; };
     db.Users.Attach(user);
     db.SaveChanges();
     user.Locked = false;
     db.SaveChanges();
```

But calling SaveChanges() two times looks not good. if there any other solutions suggests me. or what is exact root cause for the problem.